# Meteorite GUI not working?

Tags: 10.10, mkv

I have installed this application here:
http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=116618

We drop a MKV file into it, and a progress bar should appear.

Seems simple. However, when I do that, I get no progress bar showed at all.

As anyone had this trouble before? Ubuntu 10.10 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like the project has died for the minute.

Quote from the projects SourceForge page:-

> This project is paused. dead. R.I.P.
>   It will be reincarnated (with God's
>   help) but don't know when.

You may want to get in contact with the developer to find out what the bug might be.

- [Meteorite](http://meteorite.sourceforge.net/) at sourceforge
- The developers [site](http://erdem_ua.users.sourceforge.net/)

Other than that running the program from terminal will give you an idea if its working or not and if not why. If you add the output of terminal it's possible there maybe a fix but I can't guarantee anything as by the developers own admission the project is dead.